# Can't pass global variables inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, loops, variables

I'm trying to run a FOR loop with variables that need to re-run again in another function and I need to code them out of the first function,
But the function receive them as "undefined".

When the variables are local inside the collectionChecking function except of ledTypes2 the variable of hostIndx2 is undefined when the function of handleResponse2 is trying to call him. This function should render the response as an icon from the method of ledTypes2 inside the HTML page.

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

var ledTypes = {
    green: "<img id='logo' src='green.png' height='30' width='30'>",
    red: "<img id='logo' src='red.png' height='30' width='30'>",
    yellow: "<img id='logo' src='yellow.png' height='30' width='30'>"
};

var hosts2 = ['http://host1.com','host2.com','host3.com','host4.com'];
var hostIndx2 = 0;

var lengthVal = hosts2.length;
var token = '1213232431';
    function collectionChecking() {

        console.log("im inside the func" + hostIndx2 + "---" + lengthVal);
        for (; hostIndx2 < lengthVal; hostIndx2++) {
            console.log(hostIndx2);
            let url = hosts2[hostIndx2];
            // sendReq();
            fetch(url , {method: 'GET', headers:{"X-AUTH-TOKEN": token, "Content-Type": "text/plain"}, timeout: 30000}
            ).then(function (res, hostIndx2) {
                    console.log(res.status, hostIndx2);
                    handleLedResponse2(res, hostIndx2);

                });
        }
    }

function handleLedResponse2(res, hostIndx2) {
    var curSpan = document.getElementById('col_host_' + hostIndx2);
    console.log("IM HERE" + res.status + "---" + hostIndx2);
    if (res.status === 200 || res.status === 204) {
        curSpan.innerHTML = ledTypes.green;
    } else if (res.status === 500 || res.status === 404) {
        curSpan.innerHTML = ledTypes.red;
    } else if (res.status === 300 || res.status === 301 || res.status === 302) {
        curSpan.innerHTML = ledTypes.yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem you're having.  Which exact variables are undefined and on what line of code?  And, what does "need to code them out of the first function" mean?  Please be more specific about exactly what problem you have and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, the variable of hostIndx2 is undefined when the function of handleResponse2 is trying to call him. This function should render the response as an icon from the method of ledTypes2 inside the HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong in this code.

For starters, you can't use a `for` loop index variable like that in an asynchronous response.  The `for` loop will have completely finished before `handleLedResponse2()` is called and thus it will not have the desired value.

Secondly, you're declaring a `.then()` handler to have two arguments on this line:

```
.then(function (res, hostIndx2) {
```

By specification a `.then()` handler is passed only one argument.  Thus you're defining an argument named `hostIndx2` that will always be `undefined` and it will "hide" the higher scoped variable of the same name so you cannot access it.
 That is why you are seeing the value always be `undefined`.  The first thing to fix is to change the above code to just this:

```
.then(function (res) {
```

That will give you access to the higher scoped `hostIndx2` variable (it will no longer be `undefine`).  But, it probably won't have the desired value because of the mixing of a synchronous `for` loop and asynchronous `fetch()` calls as the `for` loop will have run to completion before any `fetch().then()` handlers get called.

I think that explains what is wrong with this part of the code, but I can't quite recommend the complete fix because I don't know for sure what you're trying to do.  I would theorize that `hostIndx2` should not be a higher scoped variable at all as this just causes problems and makes opportunities for other things to trounce it.  It should likely be a local variable and then you should pass it as an argument to whatever you want to have access to it.

To fix the problem accessing it asynchronously, there are multiple options.  You can switch to defining it in the `for` loop itself with `let` and each invocation of the loop will get its own separate version of the variable (solving the async access issue).  Or, you could change your loop to use `forEach` which will create a new unique scope for each invocation of the loop.

---

With a few guesses about what you're trying to do, here's a cleaned up version:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const ledTypes = {
    green: "<img id='logo' src='green.png' height='30' width='30'>",
    red: "<img id='logo' src='red.png' height='30' width='30'>",
    yellow: "<img id='logo' src='yellow.png' height='30' width='30'>"
};

const hosts2 = ['http://host1.com','http://host2.com','http://host3.com','http://host4.com'];
const token = '1213232431';

function collectionChecking() {
    hosts2.forEach(function(url, index) {
        console.log("im inside the func" + index);
        fetch(url , {method: 'GET', headers:{"X-AUTH-TOKEN": token, "Content-Type": "text/plain"}, timeout: 30000}).then(function (res) {
            console.log(res.status, index);
            handleLedResponse2(res, index);
        });
    }
}

function handleLedResponse2(res, hostIndx2) {
    let curSpan = document.getElementById('col_host_' + hostIndx2);
    console.log("IM HERE" + res.status + "---" + hostIndx2);
    if (res.status === 200 || res.status === 204) {
        curSpan.innerHTML = ledTypes.green;
    } else if (res.status === 500 || res.status === 404) {
        curSpan.innerHTML = ledTypes.red;
    } else if (res.status === 300 || res.status === 301 || res.status === 302) {
        curSpan.innerHTML = ledTypes.yellow;
    }
}
```

---

P.S. I'm a bit confused here because your question is tagged as node.js and it appears you're using node-fetch (which implies a node.js environment), but then you show `document.getElementById()` which is not something you can use in node.js - that would normally be code that would run in a browser.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your solutions and let you know the results. It's my first time I'm handling in this use case and I have a lot of problems on the way. The rational of this code is to send GET request to a multiple hosts and render their responses in saperated span tags in the HTML page, kind of dashboard. But this is a cross domain request so I'm using the fetch function instead of the XMLhttp handler.